# React-jss: Warning: Rule is not linked. Missing sheet option "link: true"

Tags: reactjs, jss

I'm trying to change the underline border-color of a Material-UI input component. But the following code doesn't work and gives me the following error:

Warning: Rule is not linked. Missing sheet option "link: true"

These are my imports:

```
import React from "react";
import classNames from "classnames";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import injectSheet from "react-jss";
import customInputStyle from "../../assets/jss/material-dashboard-react/components/customInputStyle.jsx";
```

These are the class names combined:

```
  const underlineClasses = classNames({
    [classes.underlineError]: error,
    [classes.underlineSuccess]: success && !error,
    [classes.underlineCustom]: customColor,
    [classes.underline]: true
  });
```

If the error or succes props are true, it does show the right color. I want to set the underline color based on the prop customColor if its defined, so I can't define a static color.

This is the component that uses the combined class names:

```
  <Input
    classes={{
      underline: underlineClasses
    }}
  />
```

This is the style object:

```
const customInputStyle = {
  underline: {
    "&:hover:not($disabled):before,&:before": {
      borderColor: "#D2D2D2 !important",
      borderWidth: "1px !important"
    },
    "&:after": {
      borderColor: primaryColor
    }
  },
  underlineError: {
    "&:after": {
      borderColor: dangerColor
    }
  },
  underlineSuccess: {
    "&:after": {
      borderColor: successColor
    }
  },
  underlineCustom: {
    "&:after": {
      borderColor: props => props.customColor
    }
  }
}
```

this is how I export the component:

```
export default injectSheet(customInputStyle, { link: true })(CustomInput);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function values in nested rules are not supported yet, follow the v10 release updates in this issue https://github.com/cssinjs/jss/issues/795

Comment: I'm a bit confused because the function values inside of media queries are working for me even though I'm getting the warning.  I'm using  react-jss 8.6.1

Comment: I'm using v10.0 of the JSS and it is still throwing the warnings. Even though it renders the style but it throws the warnings. Has anyone got around these warnings on v10.0?

Answer (score 3):

You should use `::after` instead of `:after`, look at https://github.com/cssinjs/jss/issues/710 and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements